# js вызов метода из метода

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
class Place {
    constructor(object) {
        this.role = 5;

        // как обратится к setRole(r) ??
    }
    setRole(role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    build {
        // как обратится к setRole(r) ??
    }
}
```

Comment: а в чем проблема заключается?

Comment: Сейчас бред скажу, но может... через `this`?

Answer (score 2):

Да просто через `this.`
 Плюс Вы скобки у объявления метода забыли.

```
build(){
    var role = Math.random();
    this.setRole(role); 
}
```